# Rails database migration failing because of Postgres inet type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, devise

I have a Rails(4.1.0) app that works fine on Heroku. However, on my local machine, rake db:migrate fails due to a table for devise that uses inet datatype and I am using sqlite3 for testing.

I have included the postgres gem as well as postgres_ext but still coming up with the error:

```
undefined method `inet' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0x00000005fae9e8>/home/app/db/migrate/20141107192501_add_devise_to_users.rb:19:in `block in up'
```

Comment: What is the offending devise module?

Comment: Trackable, when it tries to create the table columns for current_sign_in_ip and last_sign_in_ip. Both of which are type inet.

Comment: Is using Postgres locally an option?

Comment: It is, and I have postgres 9.3 installed. I added pg gem for dev environment but still getting the same issue. I feel there's something here I'm missing entirely.

Comment: Do you have Postgres set up in your `database.yml`?

Comment: Ah damnit, it's always something easy! That got me on the right track. I had to set up the adapter and set the db. Thanks @papirtiger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If testing locally using Postgres is acceptable just setup the correct adapters. A sample `database.yml`:

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  template: template0 # Required for UTF8 encoding
  username: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] %>
  host: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_HOST"] %>

development:
  <<: *common
  database: 'my_app_dev'

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *common
  database: 'my_app_test'
```